# Joining Two Tables With Different Columns and Formats Based on One Common column - Need to Show Duplicates

Tags: mysql, union

I have two tables showing different information regarding the same ID, which is also the only common column in both tables.

I need to compile a table with:

- all instances, including duplicates. Meaning I need to have multiple rows with the same ID.
- Only ones where the delivery was successful, i.e - delivery_status = completed.

I ran the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mistakes
LEFT JOIN Delivery ON mistakes.id = Delivery.id

UNION

SELECT * FROM mistakes
RIGHT JOIN Delivery ON mistakes.id = Delivery.id 
WHERE delivery_status = "Completed";
```

- Checking the rows in excel gives me 7 results but mysql gives me only 3, with a few rows missing because of identical id's.
- Trying it with UNION ALL gives me too many results, not the sum of rows in the tables but higher
- In the new table I still see rows that the delivery_status is not completed (no_answer). Why is that?

Addition: the data tables:

The mistake event table:

```
id  event_type  Employee_id
eedbdc4a    Mistake 28060
ee46766e    Mistake 24138
ecf7b502    Mistake 29761
ebb004b0    Mistake 27631
eedbdc4a    Mistake 32085
ee46766e    Mistake 31217
ecf7b503    Mistake 32085
ebb004b1    Mistake 7529
eedbdc4a    Mistake 4637
ee46766e    Mistake 11685
```

All deliveries table:

```
request_id  accepted_ts Employee_id ride_status pickup_ts   dropoff_ts
33269979    04-06-17 8:05   10180   Completed   06-04-17 8:20   06-04-17 8:24
33270327    04-06-17 8:17   4637    No_answer   06-04-17 8:25   06-04-17 8:29
33270441    04-06-17 8:21   15632   Cancelled   06-04-17 8:33   06-04-17 8:36
33270465    04-06-17 8:22   10940   Completed   06-04-17 8:30   06-04-17 8:46
33270548    04-06-17 8:25   7264    No_answer   06-04-17 8:25   06-04-17 8:26
33270734    04-06-17 8:37   15632   Cancelled   06-04-17 8:42   06-04-17 8:48
33270770    04-06-17 8:44   24138   Completed   06-04-17 8:47   06-04-17 8:52
33270810    04-06-17 8:52   13851   No_answer   06-04-17 8:55   06-04-17 9:00
33270957    04-06-17 9:32   11561   Cancelled   06-04-17 9:33   06-04-17 9:38
33271104    10-22-17 10:20  7529    Completed   10-22-17 10:30  10-22-17 10:42
33271251    10-22-17 8:20   2322    No_answer   10-22-17 8:30   10-22-17 8:30
33271398    10-22-17 22:20  10345   Cancelled   10-22-17 22:56  10-22-17 22:56
33271545    10-22-17 10:24  28060   Completed   10-22-17 10:44  10-22-17 10:24
33271692    10-22-17 10:04  55231   No_answer   10-22-17 10:24  10-22-17 10:04
33271839    10-22-17 12:20  3453    Cancelled   10-22-17 12:50  10-22-17 12:20
33271986    10-22-17 2:20   19887   Completed   10-22-17 2:35   10-22-17 2:20
33272133    10-22-17 22:00  17342   No_answer   10-22-17 22:20  10-22-17 22:40
33272280    10-22-17 10:40  11685   Cancelled   10-22-17 11:02  10-22-17 10:40
33272427    10-22-17 18:20  29761   Completed   10-22-17 18:50  10-22-17 18:20
33272574    10-22-17 5:20   3443    No_answer   10-22-17 5:55   10-22-17 5:20
33272721    10-22-17 10:20  55221   Cancelled   10-22-17 10:30  10-22-17 10:20
```

Comment: Please show the table data

Comment: sure, added to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` clause implicitly converts `RIGHT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM mistakes
RIGHT JOIN Delivery ON mistakes.id = Delivery.id 
WHERE delivery_status = "Completed";
```

instead use

```
SELECT * FROM mistakes
LEFT JOIN Delivery ON mistakes.id = Delivery.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM mistakes
RIGHT JOIN Delivery ON mistakes.id = Delivery.id 
       AND delivery_status = "Completed";
```

This query will give you records which are included in mistakes table regardless of having related data in Delivery table plus records included in Delivery table where their status is equal to Completed joined by mistakes regardless related records exists in mistakes table.

Comment: Didn't know that about the "where" clause, thank you.

I used your syntax but it still gave me too many results, with different status.

I might have made a mistake in an earlier step? setting up the tables?

Comment: without seeing expected output it is hard to make comment, please add expected output into your question

Comment: Thanks for the help, I leaned on some friends of mine and managed to finish it.